# View entire text in column in Navicat results window

Tags: postgresql, navicat

I've just installed Navicat Version 11.0.10 for PostgreSQL and when I execute a query in the query editor I notice that I can only view the top line of the text in any of the result's fields. I can't see a way to set the editor to show the entire text in a column when I click on it.

I'm sure when using Navicat for MYSQL previously I didn't have this problem. Any ideas how to configure the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a memo button on the toolbar that allows me to view the entire contents of the cell.